# Set Django model field by choice text name

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider the following example model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    TYPE_ONE = 1
    TYPE_TWO = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (TYPE_ONE, "One"),
        (TYPE_TWO, "Two"),
    )

    type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    #  ... other fields
```

This works well internally, as I now have a 'constant' which I can reuse throughout my code to refer to each `type`.

However, when this model gets serialized and sent to the client as JSON through a custom API Controller implementation, it turns the type into it's textual representation. It might look like this:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'type': 'One'
}
```

This is fine, however I'd like to be able to *set* the field value based on this text version (the consumer of my API wants to be able to pass friendly strings, not ints).

When constructing a model instance, how can I set `type` to `One`, and have it automatically convert it into the relevant `int`?

Something like:

```
m = MyModel()
m.type = "One"
m.save()  # throws a ValueError
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you use for serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this workaround:

```
m.type = dict((key,value) for (value,key) in MyModel.TYPE_CHOICES)['One']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make one property for it. So you can use whenever you want.

```
class MyModel(object):
     TYPE_CHOICES = ((1, "One"), (2, "Two"))
     type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

     def getx(self):
         return self.type

     def setx(self, val):
           ch = filter(lambda y: y if y[1] == val else None, self.TYPE_CHOICES)

         self.type = ch[0][0]
     type_val = property(getx, setx)
```

then save like this.

```
m = MyModel()
m.type_val = "One"
m.save()
```

it will save into type.

Hopefully, it will work for you. :)